# alignment of a flextable on the page when rendering R Markdown to MS Word

Tags: r, flextable

I've been having great luck with customizing `flextable` tables in my R Markdown documents. However, I am struggling to change the location of a table on the page. It seems the tables are centered on the page by default. I'd like one of my tables aligned to the left margin. How do I do that?

Comment: I know nothing of this, but `body_add_flextable()` has an `align=` argument. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `body_add_flextable` is not designed to be used inside an R Markdown document (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @JDLong I have just added that functionality (in the github repo), add `ft.align="left"` in the chunk option part and voilà!

Comment: brilliant @DavidGohel! would you mind making that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @DavidGohel Is it possible to also add a similar functionality in `save_as_docx`? I usually have a list of flextables and want to save them directly in a .docx file. The resulting docx file has all tables centered

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have just added an option to enable that. Now you can use chunk option `ft.align`

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r ft.align="left"}
library(flextable)
regulartable(cars)
```
````

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for html output. Is there a way to align flextables on the left site in html?

Comment: no, it does apply to word but i can extend that to html, no problem

Comment: I would very much appreciate that, thanks in advance.

Comment: @jhvdz this is now implemented with html output, you need to update the package from github to try it (it will go on cran later)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the solution worked just fine after updating "flextable" from 0.5.4 and 0.5.5 to get this to work.