# Alignment/fitting of a flextable to page width in R

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I'm creating a pretty basic report adding small tables to a docx in a loop.
I'd like to fit them to the width of the page or at least align the table (not cells' content) to the left.
It should be quite an easy task but I found only references related to:

- alignment of cell content (package manual)
- docs built in Rmarkdown ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175351/flextable-autofit-in-a-rmarkdown-to-word-doc-causes-table-to-go-outside-page-mar),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376149/alignment-of-a-flextable-on-the-page-when-rendering-r-markdown-to-ms-word))

I tried the solutions suggested in the references but they did not work.
Here what I'm using (commented rows to show other attempts):

```
  tbl.params = flextable(fdata) %>%
    delete_part(part = "header") %>%
    #autofit() %>%
    border_remove() %>%
    border_inner_h(part="body", border = small_border ) %>%
    hline_top( border = big_border, part="body") %>%
    bold(j=1) %>%
    set_table_properties(layout = "autofit")
    #fit_to_width(7.5)
```

Am I making a mistake or missing something?
I'm looking for solutions in "pure" `Officer` (if available).

Comment: if in an R Markdown, you can use chunk option `ft.align="left"`. See https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/knit_print.flextable.html#chunk-options

Comment: sorry, I haven't been clear : I'm looking for a solution not using Rmarkdown but "pure" Officer (if available). I can't get why there's a way in Rmarkdown and not in Officer too.

Comment: the function to user is `body_add_flextable`. It has an argument align that can be set to `left`

Comment: great, thanks! I added `width(width = 3.5)` to fit the page, even if I was hoping for something more dynamic indipendent from the number of columns. If you answer I'll vote your solution.

Comment: Yes, `width` control columns widths. You can read the documentation here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/ There are lot of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script add a flextable in a docx document. The column withs are adjusted by Word and the table is left aligned:

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)

ftab <- flextable( head( mtcars ) )
ftab <- set_table_properties(ftab, layout = "autofit")
doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, value = ftab, align = "left")
print(doc, target = "fileout.docx")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there something that would do the same but in an Power Point presentation built with `Officer`?
`ph_with()` seems to place the table always at the slide's top left or placeholder's top left.

Comment: I assume you did not specify location. See here https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html#content-location

Comment: Thanks, I used `ph_location_template()` to define the offset distance programmatically.